# How to store sensor data to avoid massive data flooding?

Tags: ios, firebase-realtime-database

Just joined a group that developed some hardware, and a dozen sensor values are written into Firebase every few seconds, then synced to the cloud. Ultimately, the goal is to have two years worth of data stored and retrieved by an iOS app.

Currently, each sensor type (e.g. "Temperature") has children sample data (time/value). My concern is that over time, when an app starts up, it's going to need to grab a massive amount of data. I believe it will need to retrieve all data at startup too - since it won't get childAdded events if its not running (right?).

I'm thinking that having each sensor have children of "day" (a 24 hour period) would work much better. The app could then hopefully just ask for the values of the child date that hasn't been cached elsewhere - just a 24 hour period or at most a few days (where the app wasn't running).

Does this schema have better properties than having all sample values under each sensor parent?

Comment: Why do you need to load the data at startup? You can simply perform a query to pull data from firebase at query time (aka, when the data is needed) as opposed to refreshing the local database every time the app starts up. We need more information on your design and purpose to provide a suggestion.

Comment: Also, can you please elaborate on your statement "since it won't get childAdded events if its not running" what do you mean by childAdded events?

Comment: @Philippe The app stops running for a few hours. Data is added but the app didn’t get notified - it’s not running. Then  app restarts, data is out of date. So it essentially must force Firebase to resync with server. As I understand it ios Firebase has to get all external data before it can reconcile local with remote. Normally app gets childAdded events when new sensor data is added to server side.

Comment: @Philippe it’s a moot issue now - my boss didn’t see any problem with current design and I’m off the project. I was just trying to get a proper architecture in place - any issues won’t show up until there really is a large repository. And my fears may well be misplaced.